# Pandas Group by before outer Join

Tags: pandas, join, group-by

I have two tables with the following formats:

Table1: key = Date, Index

```
    Date      Index  Value1
0   2015-01-01  A   -1.292040
1   2015-04-01  A   0.535893
2   2015-02-01  B   -1.779029
3   2015-06-01  B   1.129317
```

Table2: Key = Date

```
    Date        Value2
0   2015-01-01  2.637761
1   2015-02-01  -0.496927
2   2015-03-01  0.226914
3   2015-04-01  -2.010917
4   2015-05-01  -1.095533
5   2015-06-01  0.651244
6   2015-07-01  0.036592
7   2015-08-01  0.509352
8   2015-09-01  -0.682297
9   2015-10-01  1.231889
10  2015-11-01  -1.557481
11  2015-12-01  0.332942
```

Table2 has more rows and I want to join Table1 into Table2 on Date so I can do stuff with the Values. However, I also want to bring in Index and and fill in for each index, all the Dates they don't have like this:

Result:

```
    Date    Index   Value1      Value2
0   2015-01-01  A   -1.292040   2.637761
1   2015-02-01  A   NaN         -0.496927
2   2015-03-01  A   NaN         0.226914
3   2015-04-01  A   0.535893    -2.010917
4   2015-05-01  A   NaN         -1.095533
5   2015-06-01  A   NaN         0.651244
6   2015-07-01  A   NaN         0.036592
7   2015-08-01  A   NaN         0.509352
8   2015-09-01  A   NaN         -0.682297
9   2015-10-01  A   NaN         1.231889
10  2015-11-01  A   NaN         -1.557481
11  2015-12-01  A   NaN         0.332942
.... and so on with Index B
```

I suppose I could manually filter out each Index value from Table1 into Table2, but that would be really tedious and troublesome if I didn't actually know all the indexes. I essentially want to do a "Table1 group by Index and right join to Table2 on Date" at the same time, but I'm stuck on how to express this.

Running the latest versions of Pandas and Jupyter.

EDIT: I have a program to fill in the NaNs, so they're not a problem right now.

Comment: Can you explain why you have null values on Value1 after the join from Table 1 to Table 2, but you do not have null values for Index? Is it that Value1 has null values on Table 1 but Index does not, or do you have other logic when assigning an Index value to a Date on Table 2 that does not exist on Table 1?

Comment: I apologize if it was unclear. The result table was an example of what I was looking for and created manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to merge `'Value1'` of `df1` with `df2` on `'Date'`, while assigning the Index to every date. You can use `pd.concat` with a list comprehension

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df2.assign(Index=i).merge(gp, how='left') for i, gp in df1.groupby('Index')],
          ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
          Date    Value2 Index    Value1
0   2015-01-01  2.637761     A -1.292040
1   2015-02-01 -0.496927     A       NaN
2   2015-03-01  0.226914     A       NaN
3   2015-04-01 -2.010917     A  0.535893
4   2015-05-01 -1.095533     A       NaN
5   2015-06-01  0.651244     A       NaN
6   2015-07-01  0.036592     A       NaN
7   2015-08-01  0.509352     A       NaN
8   2015-09-01 -0.682297     A       NaN
9   2015-10-01  1.231889     A       NaN
10  2015-11-01 -1.557481     A       NaN
11  2015-12-01  0.332942     A       NaN
12  2015-01-01  2.637761     B       NaN
13  2015-02-01 -0.496927     B -1.779029
14  2015-03-01  0.226914     B       NaN
15  2015-04-01 -2.010917     B       NaN
16  2015-05-01 -1.095533     B       NaN
17  2015-06-01  0.651244     B  1.129317
18  2015-07-01  0.036592     B       NaN
19  2015-08-01  0.509352     B       NaN
20  2015-09-01 -0.682297     B       NaN
21  2015-10-01  1.231889     B       NaN
22  2015-11-01 -1.557481     B       NaN
23  2015-12-01  0.332942     B       NaN
```

By not specifying the merge keys, it's automatically using the intersection of columns, which is `['Date', 'Index']` for each group.

Comment: That's a really neat list comprehension. I didn't you could split off groupby object like that. One last thing, while it's clear that you aren't having this problem, the Value1's aren't showing up for my in my Jupyter notebook. The groupby is working, but the merge is acting up. Does you know anything about this?